# Problem with cors policy and capacitor android platform

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, react-native, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have a cors error when making a call to the backend (asp.net core api)

the point is in website it works fine but when converting it to mobile app the problem appears.

the configuration for cors policy in the backend

```
services.AddCors(opt => opt.AddPolicy("allowLocalAtPort5173", builder =>
    {
        builder
            .WithOrigins("http://<my-public-ip>","https://localhost:8100","https://localhost","http://localhost:8100","http://localhost","http://localhost:5173", "http://localhost:5174","http://localhost:3000")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials()
            .Build();
    }));
```

and

```
app.UseCors("allowLocalAtPort5173");
```

the configuration for the capacitor config file

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.college',
  appName: 'college',
  webDir: 'dist',
  server: {
    androidScheme: 'https',
  }
};

export default config;
```

I have no idea why the problem occurs